# Getting upperbound and lowerbound from a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to figure out the code for a project but I don't completely understand it. The objective is to write a program that generates a set of 10 random numbers and stores it in an array (the 10 numbers display in the textbox correctly). It should have a button that will compute the minimum, maximum and average of the array. I cant seem to get the max and min values of it from a textbox. I know people don't post the answers and I'm not looking for that but if someone could tell my why what I'm doing for the max/min is wrong or point my in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thank you!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim randomArray As New Random()
    Dim randomNumber As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        randomNumber = randomArray.Next(1, 101)
        displaynumbersTextBox1.AppendText(randomNumber & " ")
        displaynumbersTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim randomArray As New Random()
    Dim randomNumber As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        randomNumber = randomArray.Next(1, 101)
        displaynumbersTextBox1.AppendText(randomNumber & " ")
    Next

    Dim min As Integer
    min = displaynumbersTextBox1.Text.GetLowerBound()
    displayminTextBox2.Text = min
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to get the logic outside the button click handlers (and name those buttons for the love of all that is good!), so that *Button2* can know what *Button1* did.

Comment: `people don't post the answers`  *what????* SO is all about answers.  When you post your numbers to the TextBox they become text, which do not average (what is the average of "foo" and "red"?).  Second, the textbox is not going to know you posted an array to it.  UI COntrols make horrible variables.  Use an array, do the math and show the user the results in UI Controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, I see this code in Button1:

```
TextBox1.AppendText(randomNumber & " ")
TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber)
```

The 2nd line negates the first. Just remove it. Instead, clear the textbox at the beginning of the button click handler.

Next, in button 2 the code goes through and re-creates a new set of random numbers, instead of using the set created from the first button. What is more, at no point are the numbers ever stored in an array. You need an array declared outside of either button, in in the code for Button1 set the elements of the array, so you can use those numbers again in Button2 more easily.